# Округлить число до сотен, 10005 до 10100

Tags: python, математика

как окргулить число именно до сотен, например:

```
12003 - 12100
10135 - 10200
5711 - 5800
```

Comment: Разделить на 100, Округлить вверх, Умножить на 100 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - добавить к числу +50, а потом уже округлять до сотен.

```
print round(12003 + 50, -2) 
print round(10135 + 50, -2)
print round(5711 + 50, -2)
```

+50 нужно для того, чтобы обычное "стандартное" округление, работало как округление "вверх".

Comment: У вас второй питон - print без скобок? )

Comment: @CrazyElf какой открылся по фразе "python sandbox online" на том и пишу.